# Getting child elements using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I've got the following HTML code:

```
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu" style="z-index: 1; top: 251px; left: 37px;">
    <ul class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-corner-bottom" aria-hidden="true" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-191-button" id="gwt-uid-191-menu" style="width: 270px; height: auto;" aria-disabled="false" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-999">
        <li role="presentation" class="ui-selectmenu-item-selected">
          <a href="#nogo" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="ui-selectmenu-item-999">All Applications</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="">
          <a href="#nogo" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">Option Alpha</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="ui-corner-bottom">
          <a href="#nogo" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">Option Beta</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
<div class="ui-selectmenu-menu"...>...</div>
```

I'm able to get the WebElement for `ui-selectmenu-menu` like this (there are many on the page; hence, the use of `findElements`) :

```
List<WebElement> dropdowns = driver.findElements(By.className("ui-selectmenu-menu"));
```

And the `ul` below it like this:

```
WebElement ddChild = dropdowns.get(0).findElement(By.className("ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown"));
```

I'm even able to grab all the `li` under the `ddChild` like this:

```
List<WebElement> ddOpts = ddChild.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='gwt-uid-191-menu']/li[*]"));
```

But the problem that I can't seem to figure out how to grab the text-value of the `<a href="#nogo"...` tag under each `li` element.

I'd like to be able to loop through all the `ddOpts` and grab the `<a href="#nogo"...` text values and save them to an `ArrayList<String>`.

So, for example, my first `ArrayList<String>` value would contain `All Applications`, then `Option Alpha`, then `Option Beta`, and then jump to the next `ul` element from the next `dropdowns` and do the whole process again, all while adding to the `ArrayList<String>`.

I'm sure its a simple solution but I've got limited experience with Selenium WebDriver.

Thanks!

*PS: Is there a simple way to grab the child of a WebElement?*

Comment: did you try using the .getCssValue("href") value of the li element ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> ddOpts = ddChild.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='gwt-uid-191-menu']/li/a"));
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement we : ddOpts) {
    links.add(we.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the `href` attribute of the `WebElement` (referring to the anchor tag `<a>` in this example, do this:

```
List<WebElement> ddOpts = ddChild.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='gwt-uid-191-menu']/li/a"));
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement we : ddOpts) {

    // ADD all the href attribute strings to the list
    links.add(we.getAttribute("href"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also solve your problem:

```
List<WebElement> dropdowns = driver.findElements(By.className("x-combo-list"));        
WebElement ddChild = dropdowns.get(0).findElement(By.className("x-combo-list-inner"));   
List<WebElement> ddOpts = ddChild.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"x-auto-98\"]/div[4]"));


for(WebElement we:ddOpts){
    System.out.println(we.getText());
    if(we.getText().contains("ROLE_MANAGER")){

        we.sendKeys("ROLE_MANAGER");
        we.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code will select the OptionAlpha in the dropdown of the above HTML code

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ui-selectmenu-menu')).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-corner-bottom']//**[text()='Option Alpha']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to get all the links in the `<a href`

```
List<WebElement> allLis = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='gwt-uid-191-menu']/li/a");
// Looping through above list using for-each loop
for(WebElement eachLi : allLis) {
    System.out.println(eachLi.getText());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`href="#nogo"` is same for all the anchor tags, so it might create ambiguity in selecting the item by the method

```
dropdowns.findelement(By.linktext("#nogo"));
```